# Strange facility out west near California; what is this place?

Tags: general-aviation

While on a flight to San Francisco from New York, somewhere over California or Nevada, I saw this from my window; what the heck is it?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this is an aviation facility? Is the only link to aviation the fact that you saw this while in a plane?

Comment: Honestly, no, just wasn't sure where to post.

Comment: Do you have its coordinates?

Comment: @Farhan lol, I was in a passenger plane.

Comment: @raffian It could be Area 51, that's why I asked for coordinates. Without more information, I tend to agree with the close vote. Btw, on your flight, you flew towards the East of California, then into Nevada.

Comment: Perhaps Travel.SE would've been the best place to ask.

Comment: I thought it might be Burning Man!

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone's wondering, it's the [Crescent Dunes Solar Energy Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crescent_Dunes_Solar_Energy_Project), credit to [Trish Ling](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81211/strange-facility-out-west-near-california-what-is-this-place) at Sci-Fi.

Comment: http://www.solarreserve.com/

Comment: http://www.nrel.gov/csp/solarpaces/project_detail.cfm/projectID=60